# How do I get the offline Windows drive letter from a Windows PE?

Tags: c, winapi, winpe

If I use `GetWindowsDirectory`from my online Windows, I can get the directory where the OS is installed like C:\Windows.

If I use the same function from a Windows PE, I would get like `X:\Windows`(like the screenshot), witch means the Windows directory from the Windows PE itself. How do I get the offline Windows directory? Like `D:\Windows`, or whatever letter it has.

[image]

Any function you can suggest?

Comment: Could you define what do you call 'offline Windows directory' ?

Comment: I mean. When you are in the Windows PE environment, you are using a small OS instead, and Windows gets another drive. So there is normally two drives that have all the OS folders like Windows and Program Files. I need to get the drive or directory from the offline system, not the running one.

Comment: I am using WinPE to deploy WIM images to a no-screen x86 target and the Windows directory is pointing to X:\Windows virtual folder... This Is the active OS.

Comment: I know, but how do I get the folder for the offline OS? If you switch to the other letters from PE, you will find another drive with the offline OS that you are booting from.

Comment: Yes, I see, but that offline OS Is inactive and Can not be detected by Windows API... It could be non-Windows OS.

Comment: Any idea how can I look for folders' names in the other drives?

Comment: You are talking about *the* offline OS, like there were only one. However, there can be an arbitrary number. Sounds like an XY problem, really.

Answer (score 0):

There's a utility (available in WinPE and/or Windows) called `mountvol.exe` which will list all the mounted volumes. You're winpe drive is always `x:` and the "offline" installation is often (but not always) mounted at `d:`.

There are Windows APIs for enumerating the volumes as well- `FindFirstVolume` and `FindNextVolume`. This will include non-mounted volumes and you can assign a drive letter to unmounted volumes.

Once you have a list of volumes, you need to look at each one to decide if it's the "target" volume you're interested in - things like volume label - the presence of \Windows, and/or examining the bcd database to determine which volumes are bootable. It's not trivial, but it is possible. The bcd database is actually a windows registry hive that you can mount read-only...and it's a job to tease the information out of it.

Even if the offline volume isn't mounted (which would be unusual), you can still examine the volume contents using windows APIs - but you have to use the `\\?\` prefix and the volumeID (rather than the drive letter). It's easier to just mount the volume.

If you genuinely can't find the offline volume, check to make sure if the physical disk is present. If it's not, you may need to add drivers for the particular hard drive to your winPE image. Typically, you can get these from a running OS that uses the drive. There's an `/addDriver` subcommand in DISM to copy drivers from a driver store. Folks often just point to the existing driver store on the computer where you're building the `.wim`.